# в нескольких десятках(-ов) футов (окончание)

Tags: стилистика, падежи, окончания

«Он находился от них всего в нескольких десятках(-ов) футов, но всё равно думал о проблемах». 
Какой вариант правильный?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Он находился от них всего **в нескольких десятках футов**, но всё равно думал о проблемах.*

***В нескольких  десятках футов*** — согласование в П.п., основное правило для числовых оборотов. Числительное задает родительный падеж существительному (десяток) в И.п. и В.п. и согласуется с ним в остальных падежах.

Получаем: (И.п.) несколько десятков футов —  (П.п.) в нескольких десятках футов.

***Несколько*** — неопределенное числительное.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon!

Comment: *Числительное задает родительный падеж существительному (десяток) в И.п. и В.п. и согласуется с ним в остальных падежах.* Запутался. Ведь "в нескольких десятках футов" у десятка П. п., а не родительный.

Comment: Числовой оборот:  1)  несколько (числ. И.п.) десятков (сущ. Р.п.). Числительное задает Р.п. существительному. 2) В нескольких (П.п.)  десятках (П.п.) - числительное согласуется с сущ. в П.п.